# Git push will push my changes to what branch?

Tags: git, github

I created a local branch(XYZ) and checked out code from remote branch(ABC). 
my local branch name and remote branch names are not same.

I published/pushed my branch(XYZ) to git.

there were some changes on the initial remote branch(ABC) where I got my code from.

how to get those changes(changes from ABC branch on remote) into my local branch(XYZ) and push them to my remote branch(XYZ)?

I set up stream branch to ABC and did git pull. so changes came and I could see there were some commits to make. Just confused, If I do `git push` now, where will my local changes go to? because I set up stream to ABC, do they go to ABC or do they go to XYZ branch that I published/pushed earlier.

Please help me understand. gone through git documentation but very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It will push to the "tracked" remote branch.

You could see which one for all your local branches by using the command `git branch -vv`.

Tracking a remote branch is only to be able to use the shortcuts `git push` and `git push <name-of-remote>` and git know which remote branch to update.

But you could always use the full command line `git push <name-of-remote> <name-of-the-branch-you-want>` and that will create this branch in the remote repository.

That could be useful but that should be used carefully because that could become easily a mess...

Comment: thank you. is there anyway to push to a branch that is not set as upstream. Basically, I want to work on my own branch local and remote but periodically take latest changes from another branch.. I think I should set up my own remote branch as upstream and pull from another branch using git pull origin <rmt-branch> when needed.

Answer (score 0):

**About how to get the ABC into XYZ**

Once you're checked out at **ABC** you'll need to perform the **git pull origin ABC** to make sure that your local branch **XYZ** is fully updated.

After that perform the **git checkout XYZ** and finally merge the **XYZ** using the command **git merge ABC**. If you have conflict, a message will be displayed to warn you, asking to solve the conflicts before the merge finishes.

If you push your **XYZ** branch you will send your local branch to the remote repo.

There is a good begginers tutorial in [git - the simple guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) web site.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed set different remotes, for example one to pull from and another to push to. If you already have your remote set, the one from which you pull, add one to push to :

```
git remote add upstream <url_of_upstream_git_server>
```

It won't overwrite the `origin` remote you're pulling from, and you'll be able to refer to either `origin` or `upstream` for their different purposes (typically, pulling from one, pushing to the other).

```
# for example
git pull origin master
git push upstream master
```

Answer (score -1):

When you push the change from you local branch to remote branch, you can specify the remote branch's name. By default, it will be the remote master branch.